# Setting thread culture to default

Tags: silverlight, globalization

In silverlight application I have MyTexts.resx (for english) and MyTexts.ja-JP.resx (for japanese) resource files. Before loading a page I can set current culture to japanese as following:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ja-JP");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ja-JP");
```

But sometimes I need to reset culture to default. How can I do that? The following wouldn't work:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("default");
```

OR

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Answer (score 1):

I myself seem to find an answer:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Comment: Is this actually a "Reset" for the culture?  What is actually ment by "Reset" anyway?